# Image loads as a black rectangle when the image file is stored locally

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I'm new to a-frame and created this project in Glitch.

Here is my code.

```
<a-assets>
  <img id="image" src="arrow.png" crossorigin="anonymous">
</a-assets>
<a-image src="#image" width="2" height="0.8"></a-image>
```

There is no error with the path of arrow.png because I don't get 404 error in console. If I change spelling in "arrow.png" I get a 404.

The image appears as a black box.
[image]

But if I use an online resource instead, it displays correctly.

```
<a-assets>
  <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</a-assets>
```

[image]

I created a GET endpoint in the express server that returns the image.

```
// Return arrow
path = `${__dirname}/views/arrow.png`
app.get('/arrow', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path);
});
```

When I go to the endpoint from my browser, the entire screen is black.

EDIT
Glitch project link
https://glitch.com/~quickest-catshark

Comment: Sharing the link to the Glitch project will make easier to help you.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos I edited the question and included the Glitch project link

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I have the same issue. I can see the browser fetching the image from the relative path but ar js doesn't bother to display it. Just shows a black square where the image should be

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your project structure on Glith, you need to move the `arrow.png` to your public folder.

*Remixed glitch*: https://glitch.com/~scalloped-lemongrass

Comment: I tried this locally and still the same issue with black rectangle instead of an image. In the remixed project also you have retained the external web link. Not local image.  <img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/ORJswXY.png" crossorigin="anonymous">